# Can Ubuntu run a GeForce 6200 LE and 5200 FX at once?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card, xorg.conf

I'm trying to get **both** a nvidia 6200 LE PCI-Express and 5200 FX PCI video card running at the same time in Ubuntu 9.04. This is for a triple monitor setup.

After the physical install, I verified that both devices were present.

```
>lspci |grep nVidia
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation NV44 [GeForce 6200 LE] (rev a1)
03:02.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation NV34 [GeForce FX 5200] (rev a1)
```

I also made sure the devices were present.

```
>ls /dev/nvidia
/dev/nvidia0  
/dev/nvidiactl
```

Then, I updated /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    BoardName      "GeForce 6200 LE"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    Screen         0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    BoardName      "GeForce 6200 LE"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    Screen         1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    BoardName      "GeForce FX 5200"
    BusID          "PCI:3:2:0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
EndSection
```

On reboot, only the screens attached to the 6200 came up, so I looked at /var/log/Xorg.0.log.

```
(WW) NVIDIA(0): The NVIDIA GeForce FX 5200 GPU installed in this system is
(WW) NVIDIA(0):     supported through the NVIDIA 173.14.xx Legacy drivers.
(WW) NVIDIA(0):     Please visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for
(WW) NVIDIA(0):     more information.  The 180.44 NVIDIA driver will ignore
(WW) NVIDIA(0):     this GPU.  Continuing probe...
```

I thought I would try the open-source nv driver, instead.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    BoardName      "GeForce FX 5200"
    BusID          "PCI:3:2:0"
    Driver         "nv"
EndSection
```

On reboot, the system locked up as X was starting. The last line in Xorg.0.log was:

```
(II) NV(0): Initializing int10
```

I also tried this setup with *all devices* set to use nv. I did some research on this, and turned up [the following](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg/2008-December/040970.html).

> Most of the setups with 2 graphics
>   cards are broken in xserver 1.5.x.

So I gave in and installed the [173 drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux_display_ia32_173.14.09.html).

```
>chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.20-pkg1.run
>sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.20-pkg1.run
```

After reboot, the system came up in low resolution mode. "System -> Administration -> Hardware Drivers" still showed version 180. So I selected 173 and installed again from the GUI. After reboot, I noticed that the devices were no longer coming up.

```
>ls /dev/nvidia*
ls: cannot access /dev/nvidia*: No such file or directory
```

However, the PCI system can still see the devices.

```
>lspci |grep nVidia
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation NV44 [GeForce 6200 LE] (rev a1)
03:02.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation NV34 [GeForce FX 5200] (rev a1)
```

Does anyone have experience running a nvidia card that requires the legacy driver with a newer card?

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark, but give the CUDA-dev drivers a try.
They fixed my setup when I ran with 2 different generation cards. Though mine were somewhat newer cards.

http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cuda_3_2_downloads.html#Linux